# Extjs: load external url contents as a plain/text

Tags: extjs, load

How can I load url contents like XML or JSON as a plain/text into a variable?
I don't wanna use JsonStore or XMLStore, I want to load the contents as a text.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at http://www.sencha.com/learn/legacy/Manual:Core:Ext.Ajax shouldn't you just be able to write the result into a variable?

```
var res = false;
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url : 'ajax.php' , 
    params : { action : 'getDate' },
    method: 'GET',
    success: function ( result, request ) { 
        res = result.responseText;
    } 
});
```

The example was lifted from the docs page.

Comment: I saw that... but my problem is that I want to access external url and Ext.Ajax.request doesn't have proxy for using scripttagproxy

Comment: So you're saying you want to make a cross-site request? To a URL on a different domain?

Answer (score 0):

External URL through Ajax requests are not possible. Initially when Ajax was developed. It was pretty much possible but later on due to security issues it was abandoned. You can try ajax in raw format.

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if ( xhr.readyState == 4 ) {
            if ( xhr.status == 200 ) {
              document.body.innerHTML = "GOT ACCESS";
            } else {
              document.body.innerHTML = "ERROR";
            }
          }
        };
        xhr.open("GET", "yourPage.php", true);
        xhr.send(null);
```

Try changing the yourPage.php url to some external site. You will get error in response.
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control. Read this article for more info on Cross-site HTTP calls.